# background-color transparent shows as white

Tags: css

I am having a problem with background-color transparent showing as white

Here is an example page:
   http://www.kurzweilai.net/ray-kurzweil-reveals-plans-for-linguistically-fluent-google-software?utm_source=KurzweilAI+Weekly+Newsletter&utm_campaign=0ad261ad5e-UA-946742-1&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_147a5a48c1-0ad261ad5e-281975877

the middle column is div 'wrapper'

which has the style: `background: url('../images/layout/bg_wrapper.gif') 0 0 repeat-y;`

If I go to the console and type:

```
x=document.getElementById('wrapper'); 
window.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

I get:

```
"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
```

And yet it shows it's background as white rather than the body color (yellowish green).

Why is that ?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three layers: body, #wrapper, and #wrapper-1. The background of #wrapper is a repeated bg_wrapper.gif, and the #wrapper-1 one is a repeated bg_wrapper_1.gif, so finally you see the color of the gifs. You need to remove the gifs if want to see the body background.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
#wrapper {
background: url(../images/layout/bg_wrapper.gif) 0 0
```

remove `background: url(../images/layout/bg_wrapper.gif) 0 0` and replace it with background: transparent (you don't have to, it will be transparent after you remove that..)

You can also just override using the !important selector.

```
#wrapper {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```